# Stack in C, converting infix with postfix

Tags: c, stack

**I'm trying to implement a stack in C to convert infix to postfix. But after several days of trying, im still not sure whats wrong with my code! can someone help? I made sure the line of logic is right and did on paper a lot of times, I'm new to stack, please assist!**

I'm not sure exactly where is going wrong, and after a few submissions, suddenly the same code would produce segmentation error (core dumped) without much explanation.

Examples of inputs like : (A+B)+(C-D) produces (AB)+(C+D)- As for debuggers, im sticking to simple print statements at various parts of the program, I find that theres a problem with popping the '(' at the else if (infix == ')')

Running the code in online IDEs like replit and codechef. replit produces segmentation fault(core dumped) while codechef is able to produce and run an output. <- abit confused here

EDIT: My parenthesis Else if statements arent working, but I dont see why so, I tried adding simple print statements in that else if segments but they are not showing too

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 1000 //The limit of expression length

typedef struct _stackNode{
    char item;
    struct _stackNode *next;
}StackNode;

typedef struct _stack{
   int size;
   StackNode *head;
}Stack;

void push(Stack *sPtr, char item);
int pop(Stack *sPtr);
char peek(Stack s);
int isEmptyStack(Stack s);

void in2Post(char*, char*);

int main()
{
    char infix[SIZE];
    char postfix[SIZE];

    printf("Enter an infix expression:\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c",infix);
    printf("This");
    in2Post(infix,postfix);
    printf("The postfix expression is \n");
    printf("%s\n",postfix);
    return 0;
}

void push(Stack *sPtr, char item){
    StackNode *newNode;
    newNode = (StackNode *) malloc(sizeof(StackNode));
    newNode->item = item;
    newNode->next = sPtr->head;
    sPtr->head = newNode;
    sPtr->size++;
}

int pop(Stack *sPtr){
    if(sPtr == NULL || sPtr->head == NULL){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
       StackNode *temp = sPtr->head;
       sPtr->head = sPtr->head->next;
       free(temp);
       sPtr->size--;
       return 1;
    }
}

char peek(Stack s){
    return s.head->item;
}

int isEmptyStack(Stack s){
     if(s.size == 0) return 1;
     else return 0;
}


int precedence(char item)
{
    if (item == '*' || item == '/')
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else if (item == '+' || item == '-')
    {
        return 1;
    }

    else
    {
        return 0; // if it is brackets return 0
    }
}

int isOperand(char ch)
{
  if (ch == '%' || ch == '/' || ch == '*' || ch == '+' || ch == '-')
  {
    return 0;
  }
  else 
  {
    return 1;
  }
}

int is_operator(char item)
{
    if (item == '+' || item == '-' || item == '*' || item == '/')
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

void in2Post(char* infix, char* postfix)
{
 //Write your code here

  Stack* stack = (Stack*)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
  stack->head = NULL;
  

  if (!stack)
    return;

  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  while (infix[i] != '\0')
  {
    if (isOperand(infix[i]) && infix[i] != ')' && infix[i] != '(') //NEED TO MAKE SURE HERE ISNT A PARENTHESIS 
    {
      postfix[j]=infix[i];
      j++;
    }
    else if (infix[i] == '(')
    {
      push(stack, infix[i]);
    }
    else if (infix[i] == ')')
    {
      while (!isEmptyStack(*stack) && peek(*stack) != '(')
      {
        postfix[j] = peek(*stack);
        j++;
        pop(stack);
        if (!isEmptyStack(*stack) && peek(*stack) !='(' )
        {
          return; // POPPING TILL REACH '(' IF IT IS NOT '(', RETURN
        }
        else  
        {
          pop(stack); // removing the ()
        }
      }

    }
    else // an OPERATOR IS ENCOUNTERED
    {
      while (!isEmptyStack(*stack) && precedence(infix[i])<=precedence(peek(*stack)))
      {
        postfix[j] = peek(*stack);
        pop(stack);
        j++;
      }
      push(stack, infix[i]);

    }
    i++;
  }

  while (!isEmptyStack(*stack))
  {
    postfix[j] = peek(*stack);
    pop(stack);
    j++;
  }

  postfix[j] = '\0';
  printf("THIS IS POSTFIX %s\n", postfix);
}
```

Comment: Why is the operator `%` recognized by `isOperand()` but not `is_operator()`?

Comment: oh, right. I forgot about that one. I think my main concern right now is just solving expressions with parenthesis, "*" "/" "+" and "-" it keeps producing bugs or just not the correct answer. Thanks for pointing that out though

Comment: Please provide examples of input, the expected result, and what you're getting instead. Have you tried running the program under a debugger to step through it?

Comment: Examples of inputs like : (A+B)+(C-D) produces (AB)+(C+D)- As for debuggers, im sticking to simple print statements at various parts of the program, I find that theres a problem with popping the '(' at the else if (infix == ')')

Comment: All relevant information should be in the question, not comments.

Comment: The code never initializes the `size` in the `stack` variable in the `in2Post` function. So the `isEmptyStack` function won't work correctly. BTW, you don't need the `size` at all. The stack is empty when `head` is NULL.

Comment: I see, thanks for the info! ^ The general functions are pre allocated for me, only In2Post can be edited. Thanks for the clarification, I'll edit it and try again

Comment: Thanks @user3386109 ! I found out the problem , THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad I could help. Best of luck!

Comment: Please create an answer post.

Comment: Sorry but how do I do that ? Create a new post altogether or do I just edit it at the bottom of my post?

Comment: Down the page there is an edit box titled "Your Answer"...

Answer (score 0):

The first IF statement did not take into account the character might be a parenthesis. Also, the size of the stack is not initialized.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding some code that shows the changes that should be made to the original code in order for it to work.

Comment: @AdrianMole I'll edit the post and add it into the code!